# Keep form data after validation - PHP

Tags: php, html

I can't get my form to keep the inputted data. How can I correct this code to keep the data?

**The form:**

```
<div class="nyhedsdiv">

<form name="nyhedsform" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <label for="nyheds_overskrift">Overskrift</label>
    <input id="nyheds_overskrift" name="nyheds_overskrift" type="text" value="<?php echo $nyheds_overskrift; ?>" />
    <br />
<label for="nyheds_tekst">Nyhed-tekst</label>
  <textarea id="nyheds_tekst" name="nyheds_tekst" value="<?php echo $nyheds_tekst; ?>"></textarea>
<br />
<label for="nyheds_forfatter">Forfatter</label>
<input id="nyheds_forfatter" name="nyheds_forfatter" type="text" value="<?php echo $nyheds_forfatter; ?>" />
<br />
  <button name="opret_nyhed" type="submit">Opret nyhed</button>
</form>
```

**PHP validation script:**

```
<div id="fejlbesked"> 

<?php

  if (isset($_POST['opret_nyhed']))
     {
//mysql_real_escape_string tjekker koden for symboler og sætter backslash ind foran, hvis den finder nogen.
$nyheds_overskrift = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nyheds_overskrift']);
$nyheds_tekst = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nyheds_tekst']);
$nyheds_forfatter = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nyheds_forfatter']);
$fejlbesked = '';

    if(empty($nyheds_overskrift))
      {
$fejlbesked .= '<span class="red">Du skal skrive en overskrift!</span><br />';
}

if(empty($nyheds_tekst))
   {
$fejlbesked .= '<span class="red">Du skal skrive nyheden!</span><br />';
}

  if(empty($nyheds_forfatter))
    {
$fejlbesked .= '<span class="red">Du skal skrive navnet på nyhedens forfatter!</span><br />';
}

  if(empty($fejlbesked))
    {
//Sætter nyheden ind i mysql databasens tabelrækker, der passer til navnene, som er defineret for variablerne.

$query_ind = "INSERT INTO nyheder VALUES ('', '$nyheds_overskrift', '$nyheds_tekst', '$nyheds_forfatter', NOW())";//mysql_real_escape_string tjekker koden for symboler og sætter backslash ind foran, hvis den finder nogen.
mysql_query($query_ind) or die (mysql_error());
echo "Nyheden er oprettet";

   }

else
   {
  echo $fejlbesked;
   }
}

?>

</div><!--fejlbesked-->

   </div><!--nyhedsdiv-->
```

Comment: Just a tip; write code and comments in English.

Comment: Just copy/pasted the code without thinking about it. Will keep it in mind in future posts ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using variables which are not defined here, simply change to `$_POST` array with scope for each variable you want to grab. For example

```
value="<?php echo $nyheds_overskrift; ?>"
```

Should be

```
value="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['nyheds_overskrift']); ?>"
```

Comment: Is it safe to do just that?

Comment: Thanks. It worked great. I just i would work since it is defined later. BTW: Sorry for the danish code comments. I just copy/pasted the code without giving it a thought.

Comment: @chmodder you are welcome dude. Don't forget to accept answer to  help people in the future with similar problems. To accept you just need to click on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score

Comment: For some reason, the textarea won't keep the inputted text. It would also be nice, if it would clear everything, when validation succeeds, without using ajax. I tried playing a little bit with header(location:"#");, but i can't get it to work. Maybe I should make a new post for that question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo '
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" value="'.(isset($_POST['Name']) ? $_POST['Name'] : '').'" />
</form>';
?>
```

With this, the value attribute will be filled if $_POST['name'] exists, if not, it'll be empty.

Comment: Array indices are case-sensitive.

Comment: @DanMan Thanks for pointing it out. It was a small typo, fixed it.

Comment: Thanks Richard A., but i used Fabio's suggestion. I think it looks less confusing. I just started learning PHP, so i like to keep it simple for now. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @chmodder Just trying to help. :)

Comment: Sorry, if i seemed ungrateful. I really appreciate you taking time to answer my question. For me Fabios method was just a little easer to understand and remember. ;)

Comment: @chmodder Don't worry about it, if that answer was better for you then you should stick with that one. It's about you, not me. :)